# Unable to show hidden RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a xml with one NavigationView and two different RelativeLayouts.
One of the RelativeLayouts is hidden at first (I change its visibility in the onCreate() to GONE).
When I click on a button inside the NavigationView I want the hidden layout to become visible.

This is  my Java code:

```
RelativeLayout imagenes,registro;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_invitado);

    registro = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.registro);
    imagenes = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.imagenes);

    registro.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    imagenes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    mDrawerlayout= (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mToggle= new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerlayout,R.string.open,R.string.close);
    mDrawerlayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

public void registrarse(View v){

    mDrawerlayout.closeDrawers();

    registro.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

And here the xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#fff">


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        app:headerLayout="@layout/popup_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/popup_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/imagenes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/cloud"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/registro"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#80FF4081">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/registrate"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix your code.

**1 - Fix your DrawerLayout**

`DrawerLayout` layout file must have an specific format:

```
<DrawerLayout>
    <Content Layout /> <!-- It can be linearlayout, framelayout etc -->
    <NavigationView />
</DrawerLayout>
```

You have 2 `RelativeLayout`s and one `NavigationView`. You have more items than allowed and in wrong order. So, for tests, I moved both `imagenes` and `registro` into a LinearLayout` (you could improve and keep all items inside only one relative layout.. but lets leave that for another time).

I did not change anything... I just move `NavigationView` to the bottom of the file and move both `RelativeLayout` into a `LinearLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/imagenes"
            ... >
            ....
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            ...>
            .....
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    .... />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**2 - Fix your code**

Since both `RelativeLayout` were placed in a `LinearLayout` and it is vertical aligned, `View.INVISBLE` does not work anynore for us. So, you should use `View.Gone` and change your code as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    imagenes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    registro.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ....
}

public void registrarse(View v){
    mDrawerlayout.closeDrawers();
    imagenes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    registro.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

**3 - Another possibilites**

Since your `DrawerLayout` was not properly configured, I wonder if your navigations items were being called. So, maybe, your code is not even calling `registrarse(View v)`.. However, but that is hard to cofirm with current code attached.

For any case, with the modifications I mentioned above and if your code is calling `registrarse` properly, it should work normally.

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing the `RelativeLayout` after changing it's visibility to `View.VISIBLE` because you have set the height and width of both `RelativeLayout` to `match_parent` , so the `imagenes` occupies whole screen and it is on top of `registro`.

Try putting them inside a `ScrollView` or adjust their heights or call `registro.bringToFront()` after making it visible.

Answer (score 0):

height and width of `imagenes` `RelativeLayout` is match parent so it takes whole screen..u need to set appropriate height to see `registro` `RelativeLayout` or put it in `ScrollView`